# Shortcut to select next row of vertices?

Tags: selection-tools

[image: Change Selection image]

I know how to select one vertex and then hold down control to select a vertex somewhere down the line and thus select all in between these vertices. Is there a shortcut to move to the next rank of vertices without having to repeat the process?  I am wondering if there is a shortcut to get selection B sequentially after selection A is achieved? (and simultaneously deselecting A)

Thank you.

Comment: I think you would have to develop your own Python script.

Comment: Ok. thanks. I have a lot of programming skills but have not jumped into Python (beyond changing some menu commands so they will have shortcuts in the Blender menu.)

Comment: Switch to a Text view and start with the Templates - Python - Bmesh Simple Editmode